# SQL Puzzle - Increase the value by one when two columns change value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I hate while loops and I like to avoid them when possible.

I have come across a scenario that might require a while loop to solve. However, let me ask my friends on the internet before I code a while loop.

Imagine you have the following data...

```
declare @tv_mytable table(recnum int identity(1,1) primary key, widgettype char(3), issecondarywidget bit default(0), priority int)

    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('BAT', 0)
    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('BAT', 0)
    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('ANT', 0)
    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('ANT', 0)
    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('ANT', 1)
    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('ANT', 1)
    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('BAT', 1)
    insert @tv_mytable(widgettype, issecondarywidget) values('BAT', 1)
```

You wind up with this...

```
recnum      widgettype issecondarywidget priority
----------- ---------- ----------------- -----------
1           BAT        0                 NULL
2           BAT        0                 NULL
3           ANT        0                 NULL
4           ANT        0                 NULL
5           ANT        1                 NULL
6           ANT        1                 NULL
7           BAT        1                 NULL
8           BAT        1                 NULL
```

I want a way to update the priority column so that it starts at 1 and each time widgettype or issecondarywidget changes value the priority increases by 1.

The data would look like this...

```
recnum      widgettype issecondarywidget priority
----------- ---------- ----------------- -----------
1           BAT        0                 1
2           BAT        0                 1
3           ANT        0                 2
4           ANT        0                 2
5           ANT        1                 3
6           ANT        1                 3
7           BAT        1                 4
8           BAT        1                 4
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different, albeit similar, approach to Gordan's solution using a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` to build the groups:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT tv.recnum,
           tv.widgettype,
           tv.issecondarywidget,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tv.recnum) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(tv.widgettype,tv.issecondarywidget) ORDER BY tv.recnum) AS Grp
    FROM @tv_mytable tv)
SELECT CTE.recnum,
       CTE.widgettype,
       CTE.issecondarywidget,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CTE.Grp) AS priotity
FROM CTE;
```

If you want that as an `UPDATE` then you would do:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT tv.recnum,
           tv.widgettype,
           tv.issecondarywidget,
           [Priority],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tv.recnum) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(tv.widgettype,tv.issecondarywidget) ORDER BY tv.recnum) AS Grp
    FROM @tv_mytable tv),
New AS(
    SELECT CTE.recnum,
           CTE.widgettype,
           CTE.issecondarywidget,
           [Priority],
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CTe.Grp) AS NewPriotity
    FROM CTE)
UPDATE New
SET [priority] = NewPriotity;


SELECT *
FROM @tv_mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can generate the id using `dense_rank()`.  For a unique value:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by widgettype issecondarywidget) as priority
from t;
```

If you want to maintain the original ordering, you need one more level of window functions:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by min_id) as priority
from (select t.*, min(id) over (order by widgettype issecondarywidget) as min_id
      from t
     ) t
```

To put this into an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by min_id) as new_priority
      from (select t.*, min(id) over (order by widgettype issecondarywidget) as min_id
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
     set priority = new_priority;
```